# How to change the selected item in combobox when selecting an item in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, listbox

**I'm trying to change the item displayed in a combobox by selecting an item in a listbox.** *I select different items in the listbox, but the combobox won't display any.* The combobox should been filled with the types. Beneath you see the xaml and c# code I made to simply make this work. Do you guys have any idea? The c# code is a ViewModel so I don't have any codebehind and would like to keep it that way goes I'm working MVVM.

I'm looking at this issue for a few days so any help would be grateful.

This is my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="Databinding.Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Databinding.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:TestViewModel></local:TestViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox Name="lsbPkmn" Height="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Pokémons}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="0"
                 SelectedValuePath="Type" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedType}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lsbPkmn, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"/>
        <ComboBox Name="cmbType" Margin="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This is my C# code:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Databinding.Wpf
{
    public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            Pokémons = new ObservableCollection<Pokémon>
            {
                new Pokémon {Id = 1, Name = "Bulbasaur", Type = new Type {Id = 1, Name = "Grass"}},
                new Pokémon {Id = 4, Name = "Charmander", Type = new Type {Id = 2, Name = "Fire"}},
                new Pokémon {Id = 7, Name = "Squirtle", Type = new Type {Id = 3, Name = "Water"}},
                new Pokémon {Id = 25, Name = "Pikachu", Type = new Type {Id = 4, Name = "Electric"}},
                new Pokémon {Id = 2, Name = "Ivysaur", Type = new Type {Id = 1, Name = "Grass"}}
            };

            Types = new ObservableCollection<Type>
            {
                new Type {Id = 1, Name = "Grass"},
                new Type {Id = 2, Name = "Fire"},
                new Type {Id = 3, Name = "Water"},
                new Type {Id = 4, Name = "Electric"}
            };
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Pokémon> _pokémons;

        public ObservableCollection<Pokémon> Pokémons
        {
            get { return _pokémons; }
            set
            {
                _pokémons = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Pokémons));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Type> _types;

        public ObservableCollection<Type> Types
        {
            get { return _types; }
            set
            {
                _types = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Types));
            }
        }


        private Type _selectedType;

        public Type SelectedType
        {
            get { return _selectedType; }
            set
            {
                _selectedType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedType));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Pokémon class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Databinding.Wpf
{
    public class Pokémon : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
            }
        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        private Type _type;

        public Type Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set
            {
                _type = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Type));
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Type class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Databinding.Wpf
{
    public class Type : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                _id = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
            }
        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but you should probably use an enum for your pokémon `Type`.

Comment: You forgot to show `Pokémon` and `Type`. And add some explanation: how it suppose to work and what happens instead.

Comment: Quick look at xaml reveals you are binding to `SelectedType` property different instances: pokemons and types. That wouldn't work. Instead you can bind pokemons to `SelectedPokemon` and process selection change in the setter, unless relationship is something more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here...

```
    <ComboBox Name="cmbType" Margin="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedType.Id}"/>
```

The reason your code is not working is that the selected type object does not exist in the list of combobox items.  This comparison is done by reference.  So you need to use SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath.

By the way change the name of your class Type.  This will create a lot of problems for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot this showed me how SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue exactly works, which I wasn't implementing the right way at first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify SelectedType when there has been a change. You could do it something like this

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

You'll also need to implement OnPropertyChanged - this article http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx describes how to do this.

If you do this for both your ComboBox and your ListBox changing the selection in one should change the selection in the other.

If this isn't quite what you'd like you can change the Mode variable; this article http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFBindingOptions.aspx goes through your options in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

Make **Xaml** to This:

Include namespace:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum"
                        MethodName="GetValues"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:Types" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox Name="lsbPkmn"
             Height="150"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Pokémons}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             SelectedIndex="0"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPokemon}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lsbPkmn, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"/>
    <ComboBox Name="cmbType"
              Margin="50"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPokemon.Types}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Where `Types` are just Enum in seperate class.

```
public enum Types
{
    Grass,
    Fire,
    Water,
    Electric,
};
```

and this is how your ViewModel looks now

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TestViewModel ()
    {
        Pokémons = new ObservableCollection<Pokémon>
        {
            new Pokémon {Id = 1, Name = "Bulbasaur", Types= Types.Grass },
            new Pokémon {Id = 4, Name = "Charmander",Types=  Types.Fire},
            new Pokémon {Id = 7, Name = "Squirtle", Types= Types.Water},
            new Pokémon {Id = 25, Name = "Pikachu",Types=  Types.Electric},
            new Pokémon {Id = 2, Name = "Ivysaur", Types= Types.Grass}
        };

    }

    private ObservableCollection<Pokémon> _pokémons;

    public ObservableCollection<Pokémon> Pokémons
    {
        get { return _pokémons; }
        set
        {
            _pokémons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Pokémons));
        }
    }


    private Pokémon _selectedPokemon;

    public Pokémon SelectedPokemon
    {
        get { return _selectedPokemon; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPokemon = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```